# Spring Cloud Stream dynamic destinations Avro with the native encoding is not working

Tags: avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have been trying to use dynamic destinations feature of Spring Cloud Stream to publish a message in Avro format. However, due to the fact that I am using native encoding (Confluent Avro serializer), the message converter cannot handle this scenario. Obviously, when I was using static destination I was able to manage the native encoding by using `use-native-encoding: true` parameter at the "bindings" level. However, with the dynamic destination, it seems I don't have such an ability.

```
private boolean publishMessage(byte[] record, String target, String contentType, Schema schema) {
    return resolver.resolveDestination(target)
        .send(MessageBuilder
            .createMessage(record, new MessageHeaders(
                Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType))));
  }
```

If I use the following method with content-type of "application/*+avro" with the record in byte [] format, the following exception is thrown:

```
error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@5c778504]; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema: \"bytes\"
```

This exception normally happens if you miss the native encoding property.

If I try to deserialize the byte array to a generic record before publishing the message with the following method, then it is not able to find a proper message converter for it.

```
public static GenericRecord bytesToGenericAvro(byte[] bytes, Schema schema) {
    DatumReader<GenericRecord>
        datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);

    GenericRecord record = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    bais.reset();

    BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bais, null);
    try {
      record = datumReader.read(null, binaryDecoder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Unable to deserialize byte array to avro generic record", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
        bais.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("Unable to close ByteArrayInputStream", e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    return record;
  }
```

**Update:**
After adding this bean still facing the same issue. An exception is thrown while Spring Cloud Stream tries to convert message to Avro!

```
  @Bean
  public NewDestinationBindingCallback<KafkaProducerProperties> dynamicBindingConfigurer() {
    return ((channelName, channel, producerProperties, extendedProducerProperties) -> {
      producerProperties.setUseNativeEncoding(true);
      producerProperties.setErrorChannelEnabled(true);
      producerProperties.setPartitionCount(3);
    });
  }
```

Exception:

```
failed to send Message to channel 'output1'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert message: 'GenericMessage [payload={...}, headers={contentType=application/*+avro, id=c22bf171-c6ae-cedb-b0be-3aa0fcbdf762, timestamp=1567053746112}]' to outbound message.
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$OutboundContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.doPreSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:388)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$AbstractContentTypeInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:422)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:608)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:443)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at com.example.controller.PublisherController.publishMessage(PublisherController.java:90)
    at com.example.controller.PublisherController.replayRecord(PublisherController.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the binding properties of a dynamic binding adding a `NewDestinationBindingCallback` bean and pass it into the resolver. See [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#dynamicdestination).

> If the channel names are known in advance, you can configure the producer properties as with any other destination. Alternatively, if you register a `NewDestinationBindingCallback<>` bean, it is invoked just before the binding is created. The callback takes the generic type of the extended producer properties used by the binder. It has one method:

```
void configure(String channelName, MessageChannel channel, ProducerProperties producerProperties,
        T extendedProducerProperties);
```

> The following example shows how to use the RabbitMQ binder:

```java
@Bean
public NewDestinationBindingCallback<RabbitProducerProperties> dynamicConfigurer() {
    return (name, channel, props, extended) -> {
        props.setRequiredGroups("bindThisQueue");
        extended.setQueueNameGroupOnly(true);
        extended.setAutoBindDlq(true);
        extended.setDeadLetterQueueName("myDLQ");
    };
}
```

> If you need to support dynamic destinations with multiple binder types, use Object for the generic type and cast the extended argument as needed.

**EDIT**

It's a bug in the resolver; the callback isn't called to update the properties until after the channel is created and configured. It works fine for most properties, but not this one.

Here is a work-around:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So57688303Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57688303Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewDestinationBindingCallback<KafkaProducerProperties> dynamicBindingConfigurer() {
        return ((channelName, channel, producerProperties, extendedProducerProperties) -> {
            producerProperties.setUseNativeEncoding(true);
            producerProperties.setErrorChannelEnabled(true);
            producerProperties.setPartitionCount(3);
            extendedProducerProperties.getConfiguration().put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    MySerializer.class.getName());
        });
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(BinderAwareChannelResolver resolver) {
        return args -> {
            MessageChannel channel = resolver.resolveDestination("dynamic");
            ((AbstractMessageChannel) channel).removeInterceptor(0); // only need to do this on the first resolution
            channel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        };
    }

    public static class MySerializer implements Serializer<String> {

        @Override
        public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(String topic, String data) {
            System.out.println("In my serializer with data of type " + data.getClass().getSimpleName());
            return data.getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
        }

    }

 }
```

and

```
In my serializer with data of type String
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although I can see with this approach when I intercept the binding the properties are set properly (native encoding), it still does not work for me, as the converter cannot convert this message properly. Still for some reason, the Confluent Avro Serializer is not triggered. If I remove the header of "application/*+avro" it tries to write it in JSON instead of letting Confluent Avro Serializer does the work.

Comment: The message converters are bypassed when native encoding is used.

Comment: So I guess something hasn't set properly as still the converter is involved.

Comment: Edit the question to show the updated code and configuration and I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Just accidentally updated the answer rather than the question! Wasn't able to completely revert the changes. Plz feel free to remove "something to be removed later" at the end.

Comment: I have intercepted the resolver and realized that it doesn't contain the binder properties that are added as a bean, so I guess I am missing something here as the dynamicBindingConfigurer bean is not passed to the resolver.

Comment: Thanks. I will check and let you know how it goes. BTW, is there any issue id or something I can refer to this bug later so that when it is resolved I can update my code with the proper solution?

Comment: Another question, is there any particular reason why I need to remove the interceptor on the channel before sending a message?

Comment: The resolver creates the channel before calling the callback, which means it incorrectly adds the conversion interceptor. So the work-around is to remove it before sending  to a newly resolved channel; you end up with what would have happened if the property was set before creating the channel. [I opened this issue this morning](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1799).

Comment: I was wondering if always there will be going to be a single interceptor loaded.

Comment: There is a possibility that other interceptors may be added - for example [this one in the next release](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/799eb5be289084c6227129307873cf6c41247bbb). To be perfectly safe, you can check the class name of the removed interceptor (returned by `remove()`). If it doesn't start with `MessageConverterConfigurer` add it back (at the same index) and try `remove(1)` etc.